# For loop problems in r: Error in if (length[i] == 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```
ann <- 1:2500
len <- sample(1:3,1000,replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(col1= c(1:2500),col2= c(1:2500))

for (i in 1:length(ann)) {
      if (length[i]==1) { 
            df$col1[i] <- len[i] }
      else if (length[i]==2) { 
            df$col1[i] <- len[i] 
            df$col1[i+1] <- len[i] }
      else if (length[i]==3) {  
            df$col1[i] <- len[i]
            df$col1[i+1] <- len[i]
            df$col1[i+2] <- len[i] }
}
```

Trying to make every instance of a 2 to be repeated on the following line with the number 2. Also, if there is a 3, I want the two lines following this to have the number 3. Thanks! I need practice with for loops.

```
Error in if (length[i] == 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Update: The for loop will replace every repeated row with the following numbers, I need to know how to make i+1 after every instance of a 2, and i+2 after every instance of a 3.

Comment: Overloading the function `length` by creating a variable called just like that, _when you plan to use the function itself_ seems like a disaster recipe

Comment: Dont you want instead? ```ann <- 1:2500
length <- sample(1:3,1000,replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(col1= c(1:2500),col2= c(1:2500))

for (i in 1:length(ann)) {
  if (i==1) { 
    df$col1[i] <- length[i] }
  else if (i==2) { 
    df$col1[i] <- length[i] 
    df$col1[i+1] <- length[i] }
  else if (i==3) {  
    df$col1[i] <- length[i]
    df$col1[i+1] <- length[i]
    df$col1[i+2] <- length[i] }
}```

Comment: I want every instance of a 2 to show up twice, that is I want 2 rows with the number 2 in them. And for every instance of a 3 to show up three times, so 3 rows with the number 3. The problem is that the for - loop will paste follow numbers in the repeated rows.

Comment: You might consider using the function `tidyr::uncount` which is made to do this.

Comment: As R is more focused on vectorization than on `for` loops, there is already a R function which was built for this purpose: `rep(len, times = len)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can iterate through all the elements of `len`, and for each do an inner loop that takes that element of `len` and enters it into that many rows of `df$col1`.

```
df_row <- 1
for (i in 1:length(len)) {
  for (j in 1:len[i]) {
    df[df_row, 1] = len[i]
    df_row <- df_row + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to solve this all day, thank you Jon! This worked very well