# How to skip iterations in a for loop using the next function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

```
 len1 <- sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(col1= c(1:200),col2= c(1:200))

for (i in 1:length(len1)) {
  if (len1[i]==1) { 
       df$col1[i] <- len1[i] }
  else if (len1[i]==2) { 
       df$col1[i] <- len1[i]
       df$col1[i+1] <- 2 
    next
  } 
}
```

Every time "2" occurs in the len1 list, I would like to add this in the proceeding row and skip the next iteration (i+1). Basically, I would want (i+1) every time a "2" occurs in the len1 list.

The desired final table will be longer than the len1 sample, it should be equal to sum(len1).
I would like it to look something like this: where every 2 is followed by an additional 2.

```
> df
   col1 col2
1   2    1
2   2    2
3   1    3
4   2    4
5   2    5
6   1    6
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to understand your output since you are not using `seed` for `len1`. We don't know what your `len1` actually looks like and how is desired output generated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by seed, I think this is a repeatable example. Can you better describe the issue with my data set?

Comment: run `sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)` multiple times you'll get different numbers everytime. By using `set.seed` we make it reproducible. Do `set.seed(123)` (123 or any number) and run `sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)`. You'll get same numbers everytime.

Comment: I understand now, this does not matter to me as I just want a for loop that will place a 2 in the i & i+1 row when encountering a 2 in the len1 file. When this occurs I would want to skip the proceeding i value as to not place a 1 value in the reproduced 2 row.

Comment: So if `len1` is 2 , place 2 in `i` and `i + i` row in `col1` or place 1 ? You also know that `len1` is of length 100 whereas `df$col1` is of length 200 ? I hope you also understand the importance of giving real reproducible example now. You have got 3 answers (till now) which all give different answers based on their understanding of the question.

Comment: After having posted my answer, I noticed that the OP has asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57931299/3817004) but with a better explanation of his intensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is difficult to understand. One important information is disclosed [in a comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932098/how-to-skip-iterations-in-a-for-loop-using-the-next-function-in-r#comment102281275_57932112):

> The desired final table will be longer than the `len1` sample, it should
>   be equal to `sum(len1)`

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to copy a `1` to the output vector if the input is `1` and he wants to copy two subsequent `2`s to the output vector if the input vector is `2`.

If my understanding is correct, then this is what

```
rep(len1, times = len1)
```

does.

So, with a proper reproducible example

```
n_row <- 10L
set.seed(2L)
len1 <- sample(1:2, n_row , replace = TRUE)
len1
```

> ```
> [1] 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2
> ```

```
rep(len1, times = len1)
```

returns

> ```
> [1] 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2
> ```

Of course, `sum(len1) == length(rep(len1, times = len1))` is `TRUE`.

Thus, the data.frame can be created by

```
data.frame(col1 = rep(len1, times = len1), col2 = seq_len(sum(len1)))
```

#### Fixing the `for` loop (not recommended)

If my understanding of OP's intenstions is correct, OP's `for` loop can be fixed by introducing a separate count `j` for the output vector:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = seq_len(sum(len1)), col2 = seq_len(sum(len1)))
j <- 1L
for (i in 1:length(len1)) {
  if (len1[i] == 1L) {
    df$col1[j] <- len1[i]
    j <- j + 1L
  }
  else if (len1[i] == 2L) {
    df$col1[j] <- len1[i]
    df$col1[j + 1L] <- 2L
    j <- j + 2L
  }
}
df
```

> ```
>    col1 col2
> 1     1    1
> 2     2    2
> 3     2    3
> 4     2    4
> 5     2    5
> 6     1    6
> 7     2    7
> 8     2    8
> 9     2    9
> 10    2   10
> 11    1   11
> 12    2   12
> 13    2   13
> 14    1   14
> 15    2   15
> 16    2   16
> ```

Comment: Thank you Uwe, I clearly need to learn how to make reproducible samples better. This is helpful as I am new to R and a lot of the functions are foreign to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `skip` variable that always resets to `FALSE` when set.

```r
skip <- FALSE
for (i in 1:length(len1)) {
  if (skip) {
    skip <- FALSE
    next
  }
  if (len1[i]==1) { 
    df$col1[i] <- len1[i]
  } else if (len1[i]==2) { 
    df$col1[i] <- len1[i]
    df$col1[i+1] <- 2 
    skip <- TRUE
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is great, but it is doing something that is not desirable. It is skipping over the proceeding 1's in the len1 list. Do you see the issue?

Comment: The desired final table will be longer than the len1 sample, it should be equal to sum(len1)

Answer (score 0):

To state differently, you want `col1` to be 2 if the previous `len1` is 2, but `len1` otherwise.

We can create a lagged vector with:  `c(1, len1[-length(len1)])` to determine whether a row should take the previous `len1` or a `2` as its value. A `1` is added to the beginning for the fact that the first row should take the value of `len1`.

So you can then get the desired result if `ifelse`:

```
df$col1 <- ifelse(
    c(1, len1[-length(len1)]) == 2,
    2, # if prev is 2, value is 2
    len1 #value of len1 otherwise
)
```

As pointed out in the comment, since the `sample` function is involved, it gives different result every time so there is no point to show the result here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think what you want is

```r
while (i <= length(len1)) {
  if (len1[i]==1) { 
       df$col1[i] <- len1[i] }
  else if (len1[i]==2) { 
       df$col1[i] <- len1[i]
       df$col1[i+1] <- 2 
       i = i + 1
  } 
  i = i + 1
}
```

In your question you state you want the *next* loop to be skipped, but using `next` jumps out of the *current* iteration and into the next. Using a `while` loop gives you more control over the increment, in this case we add `1` or `2` to the counter based on the value of `len1[I]`, which means we can essentially skip ahead.